# DDPG policy gradient using DeepLearning4J

Tags: deep-learning, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning, deeplearning4j

I am trying to implement the [deep deterministic policy gradient algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02971) in Java using the [DeepLearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.org/) library, but I am having some trouble with implementing the policy gradient efficiently.

In many tensorflow implementations the policy gradient is calculated using the following simple command

```
tf.gradients(output, network_params, -action_gradient)
```

Can this be done in an easy way using the DeepLearning4J library as well?

Comment: You might want to look at rl4j: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/rl4j we have a3c, policy gradients,.. and what not built already

Comment: I have studied the DQN and A3C implementations but I think this is different. DDPG has the following [policy gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blLMa.gif). The action gradient of Q is not a problem, but the gradient of the output of the policy wrt the parameters. In the other implementations a clear lossfunctions can be used but I can't figure out how to do it here. To rephrase my question a bit. 1) How do you take the gradient of the output wrt the parameters? So with 2 outputs and 10 parameters the gradient should be 2x10. 2) Can i efficiently combine it with the action gradient of Q?

Answer (score 0):

implementing policy gradient as shown in the external error exmaple worked well for me

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/misc/externalerrors/MultiLayerNetworkExternalErrors.java

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)